# Is there a way to have the tool part pane open where the WebPart zone is located?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, toolpart

If you're dealing with a page with many many vertical WebPartZones & WebParts, is there any way to have the ToolPart Pane open next to the WebPart you are editing? Or move up as you scroll up and move down as you scroll down?

It would be very helpful to be able to do this.\

&& On the same note, be able to move the Ribbon as you scroll down on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly a question about CSS. As I some what support the Javascript ideas, I must say they are a bit overkill, as you easily can edit the CSS for both the Ribbon as well as the ToolPane.

`.ms-ToolPaneOuter` this is the ToolPane CSS class you'll need to modify the CSS for.
`s4-ribbonrow` the Ribbons div ID, or if it's only the Toolbar Ribbon, it's this class `ms-cui-tabContainer`.

**Update**: I'll suggest you read [this blog](http://styledpoint.com/blog/ribbon-customization-changing-placement-look-and-behavior/), as this guy explains rather well an example of *how* you can move the ribbon and still maintain full functionality. I hope this helps you! :)

Comment: That is a good suggestion, I shall try CSS.. just setting the position to fixed should do the trick for the toolpane im guessing i think it will be more difficult for the ribbon though than just that

Comment: It worked very well for the toolpane but not for the Ribbon because the implementation of the ribbon on my master page uses javascript to hide it & I want it to maintain functionality

Comment: @MyName I'll suggest you read [this blog](http://styledpoint.com/blog/ribbon-customization-changing-placement-look-and-behavior/), as this guy explains rather well an example of _how_ you can move the ribbon and still maintain full functionality. I hope this helps you! :)

Comment: yessirry I used that and was justt about to accept your answer lol. Phanx for the wonderful answer

Comment: @MyName You are very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try editing the master page with java script. you put in some sort of on scroll down move that controls div my the distance that you have scrolled

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea but you could use jQuery [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method and copy the toolpart wherever needed. And then hide the default toolpart which pops up.